# How to find records in a dataframe using variable from another dataframe?

Tags: r

```
A

ID name_A     date
 1   DCAG   2018-1-15
 2     MA   2018-2-15

B

ID name_B      date
 1    TPO 2018-1-14
 1    TPO 2018-1-13
```

I want to find all `name_A=="DCAG"` in A, in this case `1 DCAG 2018-1-15`.Then find `ID==1`&`date>2018-1-14 & date<2018-1-16`, so the result is `1 TPO 2018-1-14`.

In other words, I want to know how to use `left_join` using numeric variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Get all the indices from A where name_a == "DCAG"
inds <- A$name_A == "DCAG"

#Get all the ID's from A where ind is TRUE
all_IDs <- A$ID[inds]

#Get all the date from A where ind is TRUE
all_dates <- as.Date(A$date[inds])

#If the date is character convert it to Date class
B$date <- as.Date(B$date)

#Select all the rows from B where the date lies in +-1 range of all_dates
mapply(function(x, y) B[B$ID == x & B$date >= y-1 & 
     B$date <= y+1, ], all_IDs, all_dates, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)


#[[1]]
#  ID name_B       date
#1  1    TPO 2018-01-14
```

It would return a data frame for each `ID`.

**Note** : To get the desired output I have used inclusive condition for `date` column

```
B$date >= y-1 & B$date <= y+1
```

This can be changed according to OP's requirements.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear.I want to find `date`in `1 DCAG 2018-1-15`, then calculate `2018-1-15 - 1` &`2018-1-15 +1` and the result is `2018-1-14`&`2018-1-16`

Comment: @wasmetqall Do you need to match `ID` as well? You have mentioned `Then find ID==1......`, hence asking.

Comment: Yeah, I want to match `ID` too.

Comment: @wasmetqall I have updated the answer. Please check.